# Is it possible to get string locator from already defined Selector in Testcafe?

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm very curios about this, and I would be really happy if there is a way to extract only string value from already defined Selector in Testcafe.

Example:

```
const element = Selector('[test-id="some-locator"]');
```

Now I need something like element.getLocator()  which can return back '[test-id="some-locator"]' value to me. I have custom method for some navigations, asserts and such, and I would like to enrich my error messages with locators and such.

In protractor there is a method ".locator()" which does exactly what I explained.

Any help would be appreciated, thx!

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at how to [extend Selectors with custom properties and methods](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402829/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements#extend-selectors-with-custom-properties-and-methods).

Comment: There's no such thing in TestCafe's documentation, so officially, there's no way. But perhaps you can use those custom properties as suggested in the previous comment.

Comment: @MartinH. Thx, I know about this! This is not what I want, the problem with this approach is that I have to define my locator 2 times, plus I need to do this on every element (I have 200+ now but, it will grow).
How can I request this functionality from the team itself?

Comment: The right approach to place your feature request would probably be raising an issue at TestCafè`s Repository on Github from [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md).

Comment: Request opened on official github from testcafe team:
https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6215